# Is there a way to "skip over" third party library calls when testing in react-testing-library? Mixpanel causing errors on test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, analytics, react-testing-library, mixpanel

I have a suite of tests set up, but ever since I introduced mixpanel a bunch of my tests have started failing in components where I utilise mixpanel.

For example, here is a cookie banner I have:

```js
export default function CookieBanner() {
  const { isValuePresent, handleAddBooleanToLocalStorage } = useLocalStorage(
    LocalStorageKeys.Cookies
  );

  const handleAccept = () => {
    handleAddBooleanToLocalStorage(LocalStorageKeys.Cookies, true);
  };

  const handleReject = () => {
    handleAddBooleanToLocalStorage(LocalStorageKeys.Cookies, false);
  };

  return (
    <StyledCookieBanner $showBanner={!isValuePresent}>
      <StyledCookieText>
        This chatbot uses cookies to improve your experience.
      </StyledCookieText>
      <StyledButtonsContainer>
        <StyledCookieReject onClick={handleReject}>
          <CrossIcon />
        </StyledCookieReject>
        <StyledCookieAccept onClick={handleAccept}>Accept</StyledCookieAccept>
      </StyledButtonsContainer>
    </StyledCookieBanner>
  );
}
```

Pretty straightforward. But then, in `handleAccept` I added `mixpanel.opt_in_tracking()` and suddenly I was getting this error:

```sh
  ● CookieBanner › should hide CookieBanner if button is clicked

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'opt_out_tracking_persistence_type')

      21 |   const handleAccept = () => {
      22 |     handleAddBooleanToLocalStorage(LocalStorageKeys.Cookies, true);
    > 23 |     mixpanel.opt_in_tracking();
         |              ^
      24 |   };
      25 |
      26 |   const handleReject = () => {
```

I guess this is because I `init` mixpanel elsewhere in my app. But does that mean I have to init mixpanel in each test as well, just to get it to work? I'm not sure how else I would mock it.

Or is there some way to skip over functionality - especially functionality from third party libs - so that I needn't worry about adding more tracking?

EDIT: Tried adding `jest.mock("mixpanel-browser");` as suggested below, but now it throws `Cannot find module 'mixpanel-browser' from 'src/components/ChatWindow/ChatFooter/ChatFooter.test.tsx'`.

I've also tried adding a `jest.config.js` with this snippet:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
};
```

But no change when I run `yarn test`.

EDIT: package.json & folder structure

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.45.0",
    "polished": "^4.1.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "parcel:build": "parcel build src/index.tsx --no-source-maps --dist-dir docs",
    "generate": "plop",
    "mockserver": "json-server --watch mockConversationData.json --port 8000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-svg-react": "^2.2.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.38.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.21",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.3",
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "parcel": "^2.2.1",
    "plop": "^3.0.5",
    "yarn-audit-fix": "^9.2.1"
  }
}
```

```
app
└── src
    └── App.tsx
    └── components
        └── ComponentName1
           └──SubComponentName1
               ├── SubComponentName1.tsx
               ├── SubComponentName1.test.tsx
               └── SubComponentName1.styles.tsx
            ├── ComponentName1.tsx
            ├── ComponentName1.test.tsx
            └── ComponentName1.styles.tsx
        └── ComponentName2
            ├── ComponentName2.tsx
            ├── ComponentName2.test.tsx
            └── ComponentName2.styles.tsx
└── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed mixpanel with npm/yarn, you can use Jest's [manual mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks) to avoid  calling any functions on the `mixpanel` object.

In your test file:

```js
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
...other imports

// This will mock all mixpanel functions
jest.mock('mixpanel-browser');

describe('your tests', () => {
  ...
});
```

`jest.mock('mixpanel-browser')` will override all functions on the `mixpanel` object, replacing them with no-ops, allowing you to call them without initializing mixpanel (and without actually firing tracking calls)

Comment: I used yarn - does that also work? Or is your advice npm-specific? I've added the snippet you suggested and it still doesn't work. Now I get "cannot find module 'mixpanel-browser')

Comment: It works the same with yarn, did you install `mixpanel-browser` with `yarn add mixpanel-browser` or are you including/importing mixpanel in a different way?

Comment: I did it with `yarn`.

Comment: If you installed `mixpanel-browser` with yarn and `jest.mock` can't find it, you might need to include more information in your question. `package.json` dependencies and your folder structure might help.

Comment: Updated with package.json and directory tree

Comment: `mixpanel-browser` is not in your dependencies, see the command above to add it. If you’re adding mixpanel as a script in the html, mocking will not work

Comment: My bad, I shared the master branch not my branch. Mixpanel-browser is in my branch. Updated the package.json.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you could try. I've got it working locally with a similar setup (deeply nested folder, TypeScript, same jest.config.js). You might try re-installing node_modules.

Comment: Re-installing node modules worked! Thanks for the suggestion. I guess I must have downloaded an outdated package by mistake or something?